# How to define Confidence Intervals from a distribution of 1000 t-statistics?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, bootstrap

I have a vector of length 300 containing some kind of values (say, scores of a math test). The distribution is not normal.
I want to test if the average score of a small group (30 samples) is significantly different from the mean of all the remaining 470 individuals.
I performed a Welch's t-test obtaining a t-statistic.

In order to validate my results I performed a bootstrapping: 
I computed 1000 t-tests from a random creation of subgroups (again,30 vs. 470) generating a distribution of 1000 t-statistics.

My question is, how can I define the Confidence Intervals for my t-statistics distribution and check if the t-statistics of the original subgroup is outside the CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is a permutation test (or more strictly, a test based on random sampling of the null distribution of a full permutation test).

If the sampling is without replacement, it's a permutation test; if it's with-replacement, then it would be a bootstrap test. Both are particular kinds of resampling-based tests and are (as you might guess) related.

(I'd recommend you consider doing it as a permutation test.)

The way you use such a distribution for a hypothesis test is to collect the results for all your resamples, and then find how far into the distribution the real sample lies (the sample value itself counts in the proportion of values at least as extreme as the one observed).

Equivalently, you take the middle $n(1-\alpha)$ values (for $n$ such resamples) as the non-rejection region, and the $n\alpha/2$ values in each tail as the rejection region.

Comment: In order words, the p.value for my observed t is given by the ratio between the number of t-statistics bigger than the observed and the total number of t-statistics? Is it correct?

Comment: If you are doing a one-tailed test yes. Otherwise you need to account for the other tail as well.